# how to run XSL file using JavaScript / HTML file

Tags: javascript

i want to run xsl file using javascript function. I wrote a javascrpt function which is working well with Firefox and Crom but it is not working on Internet Explorer

```
     function loadXMLDoc(dname)
     {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
              xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
              xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
        xhttp.send("");
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }

    function displayResult()
    {
        xml=loadXMLDoc("NewXml.xml");
        xsl=loadXMLDoc("NewFile.xsl");
        // code for IE
        if (window.ActiveXObject)
         {
             ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
             document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
         }

        // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
          {
              xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
              xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
              resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
              document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
          }
    }
```

Please help my by modifying this code or by another code so that i can work with Internet Explorer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To apply xsl trasformation I use, and promote, [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/). It is a crossbrowser library that envelope the xml apis of the different browser.

For an example of a trasformation with Sarissa you can head straight to the [howto page](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/howtos.html#transform)
but it is similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>sarissa test1</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="sarissa.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
       xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
       xhttp.send("");
      return xhttp.responseXML;
     }

     var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
     var theXML = loadXMLDoc('xml.xml');
     var theXSL = loadXMLDoc('xsl.xsl');

     // prepare the processor
     processor.importStylesheet(theXSL);

     var theResult = processor.transformToDocument(theXML);
     // now you have a DomDocument with the result
     // if you want to serialize (transform to a string) it you van use

     document.write(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(theResult));  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Quick, easy, mantained and you can focus your efforts to the xsl creation instead than struggling to overcome the browsers differences.

The single glitch, to me is a plus but someone may see it as a limitation, the code is released under GPL 2.1 or higher or, if you prefer Apache Licence 2.0 or higher

**Edit:** Mine fault, I posted an old (and wrong code) without checking it. Created a new version miming your script (and tested it) on firefox, chrome, ie8, ie7 and it worked flawlessy. I used the first two xsl/xml found on a google search (I report them below for
completeness). Try the code as is and with your xsl/xml. If it goes wrong report the malfunction too (we can be more effective with a deeper error description than *- don't work -* ). What happens when the code misbehave? (the browser freeze, report an error, return a blank result)

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xsl"?-->
<tutorials>
  <tutorial>
    <name>XML Tutorial</name>
    <url>http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial</url>
  </tutorial>
  <tutorial>
    <name>HTML Tutorial</name>
    <url>http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial</url>
  </tutorial>
</tutorials>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- try to enable/disable the xsl:output -->
<!-- xsl:output method="xml" 
                version="1.0" 
                encoding="iso-8859-1" 
                indent="yes"/-->

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>XML XSL Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
margin:10px;
background-color:#ccff00;
font-family:verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
}

.tutorial-name
{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
}

.tutorial-url
{
display:block;
color:#636363;
font-size:small;
font-style:italic;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Cool Tutorials</h2>
<p>Hey, check out these tutorials!</p>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="tutorial">
  <span class="tutorial-name"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
  <span class="tutorial-url"><xsl:value-of select="url"/></span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This set of code is also not working for Internet Explorer .....

Plz check it and help me.

Thanks