# IBM Mobile First 7.1: multipart/related Content-Type and XSL transformation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, multipart, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

I need to invoke from an HTTP adapter a SOAP service that has a `multipart/related` content type.

If I use this object as `WL.Server.invokeHttp` parameter

```
{
    method : 'post',
    returnedContentType : 'xml',
    returnedContentEncoding : 'utf-8',
    path : servicePath,
    body : {
        content : MY_REQUEST,
        contentType : "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    },
    transformation: {
            type: 'xslFile',
            xslFile: 'myXsl.xsl'
    }
};
```

I got this error:

```
"Runtime: Failed to read the HTTP response to: /MyService 
\njava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Http content type 'multipart/related' not supported. 
Supported types are: [json, css, csv, javascript, plain, xml, html]"
```

So I modified the parameter `returnedContentType: 'plain'` to obtain a result. Now the response looks like this:

```
{
"isSuccessful": true,
"errors": [],
"warnings": [],
"info": [],
"text": "--uuid:85c87f37-9436-41d1-94d4-0b944c3618b1\nContent-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=\"text/xml\";\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\nContent-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>\n\n 

MY SOAP RESPONSE 

\n--uuid:85c87f37-9436-41d1-94d4-0b944c3618b1--",
"responseHeaders": {
    ...
    "Content-Type": "multipart/related; type=\"application/xop+xml\"; boundary=\"uuid:85c87f37-9436-41d1-94d4-0b944c3618b1\"; start=\"<root.message@cxf.apache.org>\"; start-info=\"text/xml\""
    ...
}
}
```

But the xsl transformation is not performed. 
With some string manipulation on the text parameter I can obtain the SOAP response as a string but I didn't find a way(some API) to manually invoke the XSL transformation to obtain a json.

Answer (score 0):

XSL transformation is done only on the server-side (there is no manual 'activation' for it). What you could do perhaps, if you still need to do XSL transformation, is run the XSL via JavaScript. See for example: [how to run XSL file using JavaScript / HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014281/how-to-run-xsl-file-using-javascript-html-file)